# Nested Callback Scope and rootScope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller in Angular that reads some records from DB and then outputs them into a calendar. The problem is that the events array comes back as empty. I have tried using $rootScope.events as a substitute, but that gives an error "concat is not a function of undefined." What am I doing wrong? Is there some trickery with nested scopes?

I also just realized that eachActivity variable is undefined in the inner callback, as well. I assume this is a part of a general knowledge I am lacking.

```
app.controller('Calendar', ['$scope','$rootScope','$resource','moment', function($scope, $rootScope, $resource ,moment) {

    var Activities = $resource('/api/activities');
        Activities.query(function(activities){
            $rootScope.activities = activities;
            //console.log($rootScope.activities);   
        });

    //console.log($rootScope.activities);

     var vm = this;
     var events = [];

    //define the calendar on rootScope, so it has access to the Events data from the other controllers
    $rootScope.calendar = new moment();

    angular.forEach($rootScope.activities, function(eachActivity){
        //console.log(eachActivity.events);
        if (eachActivity.events.length > 0){
            angular.forEach(eachActivity.events, function(eachEvent, eachActivity){
            console.log(eachEvent);    
            var entry = {
                    title: eachActivity.title,
                    type: "warning",
                    startsAt: eachEvent.startDate,
                    endsAt: eachEvent.endDate,
                    incrementBadgeTotal: true
                }

            events.concat(entry);

            }); 
        }
    });

    vm.events = events;
    console.log(vm.events);

    vm.calendarView = 'month';

    vm.viewDate = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
    vm.isCellOpen = true;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, change

```
angular.forEach(eachActivity.events, function(eachEvent, eachActivity)
```

to

```
angular.forEach(eachActivity.events, function(eachEvent)
```

The second argument is not necessary as `eachActivity` has already been defined in the outer loop.

Also change `events.concat(entry);` to `events.push(entry);`

In addition, instead of defining calendar on $rootScope, create a calendar factory instead and inject that into the controllers where you need to access calendar data. There are a number of reasons why this is better but the simplest is that $scopes are not meant for sharing data between controllers. They are primarily meant to act as a view model to bind data between your views and controllers.

**EDIT (more details on creating a factory)**

You can define a factory like so

```
app.factory('CalendarService', [function(){
    var calendarEvents = [];  // or {} or even null depending on how you want to use the variable
    return {
        calendarEvents : calendarEvents
    };
}]);
```

In your controller,

```
app.controller('Calendar', ['$scope','$rootScope','$resource','moment', 'CalendarService', function($scope, $rootScope, $resource ,moment, CalendarService) {
    ...
    // instead of $rootScope.calendar = new moment (and I don't understand why you are assigning this to a moment but that's another conversation
    CalendarService.calendarEvents = events;
}]);
```

All you need to do is inject `CalendarService` into every controller where you need to use the events data and it will be available in the calendarEvents field.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate solution. So, does this mean that if something is defined in the outer scope, it is automatically accessible in the inner? Would this apply to many nested scopes? Is this peculiar to Javascript or AngularJS?

Comment: Regarding your architectural comment, I realized that my code is not pretty at the moment, but I am still learning Angular. How would you submit information to a service? Would you use $scope.variable as a parameter?

Comment: HI, to answer your first question, yes if a variable is defined in the outer loop it remains in scope in the inner loop unless explicitly reassigned/deassigned and doesn't need to be "passed in". This applies to every C-based programming language including Javascript. As for your second question, I will edit my answer to include some tips.

Comment: technically the bit on factories should be a different question but hey. Please if this answers your question can you please accept as the answer

Comment: Thanks. I did. I cannot up-vote because of low rating.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here:

1) The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments. You'll need to assign the vaues: `events = events.concat(entry)` for them to persist for the next iteration.

2) You have nested Angular Loops. Often necessary, but be careful with your naming conventions.

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.activities, function(eachActivity){
        angular.forEach(eachActivity.events, function(eachEvent, eachActivity)
```

Here your loops share identical argument names. This is highly discouraged because it can really create headaches for the developer trying to understand the scope of the object being iterated over. I'd suggest ensuring that your names are always unique and explicit to the scope.

3) Because you are overriding your argument names, your call to `title: eachActivity.title` is going to be looking at the inner loops second argument, which in this case is the `KEY` of the event within the forEach loop eachActivity.events object. Keys do not have properties, they are always strings - because of this your eachActivity variable is defined, yet it has no properties.

I'd suggest altering these few things and then editing your post with any progress made.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate solution. So, does this mean that if something is defined in the outer scope, it is automatically accessible in the inner? Would this apply to many nested scopes? Is this peculiar to Javascript or AngularJS?